# calculating the number of columns in a row of a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cell-array

i've got a cell array full of numbers, with 44 rows and different column length in each row
how could i calculate the number of columns in each row?*(the columns which their contents are not empty)*
i've used 2 different ways which both of them where wrong
the 1st one:

```
%a is the cell array
s=length(a)
```

it gives 44 which is the number of rows

the 2nd one

```
[row, columms]=size(a)
```

but it doesn't work either cause the number of columns is different in each row.
at least i mean the number of columns which are not empty
for example i need the number of columns in row one which it is 43(a{1 1:43}) but it gives the number of columns for each elements like a{1,1} which is 384 or a{1,2},a{1,3} and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're really asking, is "How many non-empty elements are in each row of my cell array?"

```
filledCells = ~cellfun(@isempty,a);
columns = sum(filledCells,2);
```

Comment: FYI, `cellfun('isempty', a)` is a lot faster (please see [a similar comment of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789220/calculating-the-number-of-columns-in-a-row-of-a-cell-array-in-matlab#comment25953596_17789328) to Hugh's answer).

Comment: it gives the correct answer but after running the program 3 times, there would be this error:'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'         and the error wont go unless i shut down the matlab and run it again. what is the problem?

Comment: @samdean - It's difficult to know without some more information. What is changing during those three runs? Which line specifically causes the error?

Comment: @David. nothing change actully. the code is in a separate part above all other and it wont change

Comment: thanks @David, you were right a misused variant caused the error, the problem solved by changing it

Answer (score 1):

You need to access each member of the cell array separately, you are looking for the size of the data **contained** in the cell - the cell is the **container**. Two methods

for loop:

```
cell_content_lengths=zeros(1,length(a));
for v=1:length(a)
    cell_content_lengths(v)=length(a{v});
end
```

cellfun:

```
cell_content_lengths=cellfun(@length,a);
```

Any empty cells will just have length `0`. To extend the for-loop to matrices is trivial, and you can extend the cellfun part to cells containing matrix by using something like this, if you are interested:

```
cell_content_sizes=cell2mat(cellfun(@length,a,'uniformoutput',false));
```

(Note for the above, each element of `a` needs to have the same dimension, otherwise it will give errors about concatenating different size matrices)

EDIT

Based on your comment I think I understand what you are looking for:

```
non_empty_cols = sum(~cellfun(@isempty,a),2);
```

With thanks to @MZimmerman6 who understood it before me.

Comment: You would have to do sum the results of cellfun, especially each cell contains multiple other cells, so it can simply be `sum(cellfun(@length,a),2)`

Comment: You don't have to sum them if I understood the original post - @samdean is looking for the size of each individual cell element's data.

Comment: The only reason I assumed that this was not true was because he made mention of empty content cells which would happen if it was a pure 2-dimensional cell array.

Comment: it does not give the correct answer. i try this code for a chosen example which i knew the number of columns is 43 for each row  but it gives me the number of columns of each element in a row which is 384. for example i need the number of columns in row one which it is 43(a{1 1:43}) but it gives the number of columns for each elements like a{1,1} which is 384 or a{1,2},a{1,3} and so on  which i do not really need it(thanks)

Comment: thank both of you the last code worked. i can't appreciate well enough while i don't have reputation to vote you,sorry

Comment: @HughNolan By the way, check out `cellfun` with a string function, _i.e_: `cellfun('length', ...)` and `cellfun('isempty', ...)`. Surprisingly they are [_much_ faster](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost/)...

Comment: Oh excellent, I had come across once this but I thought for some reason they had updated this. A quick check shows that they haven't (2012b): 100000 uses of `@length` takes 8.66 seconds, while 100000 uses of `'length'` takes 0.65 seconds.

Comment: it gives the correct answer but after running the program 3 times, there would be this error:'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'         and the error wont go unless i shut down the matlab and run it again. what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is something else in the program. Since you haven't shown us the rest, I have no idea.

Comment: @Hugh,thanks,i misused a varient, i correct that and the problem solved. thanks for you help